# Prove the boundary of $L$ in $C[0,1]$ is $L$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $C[0, 1]$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ equipped with the
metric
$d(f, g) = sup_{
x∈[0,1]}
|f(x) − g(x)|$.
Let
$L =\lbrace$${l : [0, 1] → R : l(x) = ax}$ for some $a ∈ \Bbb R \rbrace$.

Prove that the boundary of $L$ in $C[0,1]$ is $L$.

I have spent a few hours on this question. I have mangaged to show that $L \subset \partial L$. Now I am just having no idea about proving $\partial L \subset L.$ I really need some help. Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you prove the first part by showing that $L$ has no interior points?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes I did. $int L= \emptyset$.

Comment: All right, I too thought of the same thing. This implies that $L \subset \partial L$, right? Now, for the other way, you need to consider a limit point of $L$, and show it's in the set, am I right? Or have you approached it in another way?

Comment: Recall $\partial L$ is the closure of $L$ minus the interior of $L.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second direction, show that $L$ is closed. Then it will follow that $\partial L \subseteq \overline{L} = L$. To see why $L$ is closed, let $l_n \in L$ with $l_n \to f$. Write $l_n(x) = a_n x$. Since convergence in $C[0,1]$ implies pointwise convergence, we have $l_n(1) = a_n \to f(1)$. But then $l_n(x) = a_nx \to f(1)x = f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ so $f(x) = f(1)x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and so $f \in L$.

Comment: Alternatively, $L$ is a finite dimensional vector space and so it complete with respect to any norm, in particular the $\sup$ norm. But a complete subspace of a complete vector space must be closed.

Comment: I have not learned "uniform convergence" yet. Is it possible to prove that convergence in $C[0,1]$ implied pointwise convergence without using anything about uniform convergence?

Comment: @ButterMath: Yeah. Uniform convergence is just convergence in the metric $d$. If $f_n \to f$ in the metric $d$ then $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \sup_{y \in [0,1]} |f_n(y) - f(y)| = d(f_n,f) \to 0$ so $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.